# String hashCodes

Tags: java, string, string-literals

Small question.

```
String s1 = "test";
String s2 = "test";
```

s1,s2 both have same hashCode value

```
String sn1 = new String("java");
String sn2 = new String("java");
```

all of them said sn1 and sn2 have different hashCode values and those are different objects

When I am printing hashCode values it gives same value
  that means sn1 and sn2 points to the same object or not ?

Comment: all of whom said that?

Comment: In this article [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Nobody responding to the question that you linked to said that s1 and s2 have different hash codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often useful to look at the java code to see what is happening.

For example the `String#hashCode` method

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        int len = count;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                h = 31*h + val[off++];
            }
            hash = h;
        }
        return h;
    }
```

As you can see the result is based upon the value of the String, not its memory location.

Answer (score 3):

Hash codes should be *equal* if objects are *equal* (the reverse is *not true*, however). Since

```
  sn1.equals(sn2) // true
```

We can conclude that

```
  sn1.hashCode() == sn2.hashCode() // true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comparing Strings like:

```
s1 == s2
```

then you're comparing the pointer (the reference) of the `String`. This reference is not what you're getting from the [String#hashCode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--) method.

If you are comparing Strings like:

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

then the method [String#equals](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) uses the [String#hashCode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode--) methods of both `Strings` and compares the results.

Try it out by yourself:

```
public class StringEquality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = new String("java");
        String s2 = new String("java");

        // hashCodes
        System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
        System.out.println(s2.hashCode());

        // equality of hashCodes
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));

        // references
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
        System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));

        // equality of references
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }
}
```

Will print something like:

```
3254818
3254818
true
1072624107
1615633431
false
```

Answer (score 0):

All of who?  `sn1` and `sn2` are different objects, but they are identical, so they have the same hash code.

Comment: sn1 and sn2 are not identical, they are equal. :-)

Comment: In this article [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose That's what identical means.

Comment: As the "==" operation is often referred to as _identity_ comparison, I though it's better not to say, they are identical. Btw: I know, what you meant. And you also clearly stated that sn1 and sn2 are different objects. So everything is ok with your answer. :-)

Comment: The sock on my left foot is identical to the sock on my right foot.  But I don't have both feet shoved in the same sock.

Comment: All men are created equal - not identical